# NavController navigate doesn't work when I put a non-null value to a nullable List field of it's parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, navcontroller

I have a destination that accepts a model that have a nullable field. Before, because that nullable field isn't that important (as I have other ways to get the value of that nullable field, basically the nullable field is many-to-many relationship), I didn't bother to get that field's value on my API. But now that I have time to optimize my processes, I finally fixed my API and now I'm also passing the value of the m2m field. But, for some reason, having that value breaks the `NavController`'s `navigate()`, which was previously ok with a null value for that m2m field. Both models are already Serializable. This is the error I'm getting:

> The fragment SomeFragment is unknown to the FragmentNavigator. Please
> use the navigate() function to add fragments to the FragmentNavigator
> managed FragmentManager

My models looks like this:

```
data class Account(
    @SerializedName("id") var id: String,
    ... some other fields
    @SerializedName("m2m_field") var model1s: List<Model1>?,
) : java.io.Serializable

//Model1 seems to not need @SerializedName(), and I can use it for other Retrofit calls without any issue
//I even got an error when I added @SerializedName() to the fields
data class Model1(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") var created_at: String,
    ... some other fields
) : java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer to this. The cause was kinda silly, the reason was that I have a field on `Model1` that is alright to get null on my use-case, but I didn't declare it as nullable. And something doesn't like that. So check carefully your `Retrofit` response and it's corresponding model and make sure that they are 100% compatible.